# How to logically segment a sentence using spacy ?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am new to Spacy and trying to segment a sentence logically, so that I can process each part separately. e.g;

```
"If the country selected is 'US', then the zip code should be numeric"
```

This needs to be broken into :

```
If the country selected is 'US',
then the zip code should be numeric
```

Another sentence with comas should not be broken:

```
The allowed states are NY, NJ and CT
```

Any ideas, thoughts how to do this in spacy ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether we can do this until we train the model using custom data. But spacy allows to add rules for tokenising and sentence segmenting etc..

The following code may be useful for this particular case and you can change the rules according your requirement.

```
#Importing spacy and Matcher to merge matched patterns
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en')

#Defining pattern i.e any text surrounded with '' should be merged into single token
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'ORTH': "'"},
           {'IS_ALPHA': True},
           {'ORTH': "'"}]


#Adding pattern to the matcher
matcher.add('special_merger', None, pattern)


#Method to merge matched patterns
def special_merger(doc):
    matched_spans = []
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end]
        matched_spans.append(span)
    for span in matched_spans:
        span.merge()
    return doc

#To determine whether a token can be start of the sentence.
def should_sentence_start(doc):
    for token in doc:
        if should_be_sentence_start(token):
            token.is_sent_start = True
    return doc

#Defining rule such that, if previous toke is "," and previous to previous token is "'US'"
#Then current token should be start of the sentence.
def should_be_sentence_start(token):
    if token.i >= 2 and token.nbor(-1).text == "," and token.nbor(-2).text == "'US'"  :
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Adding matcher and sentence tokenizing to nlp pipeline.
nlp.add_pipe(special_merger, first=True)
nlp.add_pipe(should_sentence_start, before='parser')

#Applying NLP on requried text
sent_texts = "If the country selected is 'US', then the zip code should be numeric"
doc = nlp(sent_texts)
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent)
```

Output:

```
If the country selected is 'US',
then the zip code should be numeric
```